# Не могу понять, как это работает

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Имеется скрипт на Google Apps Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Utilities.sleep(getRandom(0,2)*1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  if (!e || e.value === undefined || e.value == "") return;
  //--let sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  let sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName(); 
  // sheetName

  if (sheetName == "ИЮНЬ 2023" || sheetName == "ИЮЛЬ 2023"){

    let ethisCell = e.range.offset(0,0), ethisCellRow = ethisCell.getRow();  
    // ethisCell / ethisCellRow
    if (ethisCellRow != 1) {    
      let ethisCellColumn = ethisCell.getColumn(), erightCell = e.range.offset(0,1), erightCellColumn = erightCell.getColumn(), r = e.source.getCurrentCell(), rrightCell = r.offset(0,1);  
      // ethisCellColumn / erightCell / erightCellColumn / r / rrightCell

      if (ethisCellColumn == 18 && erightCellColumn == 19) {
          rrightCell.setValue(new Date());   
      }
     }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Что есть::
нужно, чтобы проставлялась дата в правой колонке при редактировании. В среднем одновременно таблицу редактирует 10-30 человек.
Что я сделал:

```
  Utilities.sleep(getRandom(0,2)*1000);
```

Добавил паузу от 0 до 2 секунд, чтобы распределить потоки пользователей.

Что я хочу:
Чтобы скрипт работал безупречно. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как изменить/улучшить этот скрипт.
Еще, возможно, я неправильно использую flush(), и, кажется, следует добавить ScriptLock, но я не понимаю, как это работает.